# Why bean are not injected in test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testng, spring-boot-test

I have a jar which will be included in spring boot application, I am trying to do an integration test in this, the project  has the configuration class for creating the data source and JDBC template, I am using testing,

There is no application class in this project when this jar included in another project that project fetches data perfectly fine but not in same project

> spring-boot-starter-test  is added as a dependency

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
    public class DatabaseAccesManagementConfig {

        @Bean(name = "accessmngmtDataSource")
        @Qualifier("accessmngmtDataSource")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "accessmngmt.datasource")
        public DataSource accessmngmtDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "accessmngmtJdbcTemplate")
        @Qualifier("accessmngmtJdbcTemplate")
        public JdbcTemplate accessmngmtJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("accessmngmtDataSource") DataSource accessmngmtDataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(accessmngmtDataSource);
        }
    }
```

**Dao class**

```
 @Repository
    public class ResourcePrivilegesDao {
        static final  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourcePrivilegesDao.class);
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("accessmngmtJdbcTemplate")
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public List<RP> getAll() {
            log.debug("entering getAll()");
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM rp";
            RowMapper<RP> rowMapper = new RPRowMapper();
            List<RP> result = this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DatabaseAccesManagementConfig.class)
public class ResourcePrivilegesDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    DatabaseAccesManagementConfig databaseAccesManagement;

    @Autowired
    ResourcePrivilegesDao dao;

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() {
        System.out.println(databaseAccesManagement);
        List<ResourcePrivileges> list = dao.getAll();
        Assert.notNull(list, "No resource privileges found");
        Assert.notEmpty(list);
    }

}
```

test property inside

```
environment=test

#Access management db details
accessmngmt.database.url=//xxyyy/am
accessmngmt.database.username=user
accessmngmt.database.password=password
```

Comment: Try to add @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to your test class

Answer (score 5):

In the test class, you missed the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` which configure a unit test that need Spring's DI.

Take a look for the doc [spring unit test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/testing.html)

> In order for the unit test to run a batch job, the framework must load the job's ApplicationContext. Two annotations are used to trigger this:
>
> @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class): Indicates that the class should use Spring's JUnit facilities
>
> @ContextConfiguration(locations = {...}): Indicates which XML files contain the ApplicationContext.

**Notice** that, the SpringRunner is an alias for the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. So we can use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` with a shorter name.

**Updated:**

For the datasource properties injection, The `@EnableConfigurationProperties`  annotation should annotated on the Test class.

Also, you use `accessmngmt.datasource` in `DatabaseAccesManagementConfig` class, while the prefix is not matched `accessmngmt.database` in `application-test.properties`. Here you must unify them, so you can inject the properties into the bean.

Comment: SpringRunner is not found I have already addedd dependency <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
  <spring-boot-test>1.5.3-RELEASE</spring-boot-test> in pom

Comment: For `spring-boot-starter-test:1.5.3-RELEASE`, it depend on `spring-test:4.3.8.RELEASE` which is higher version than the version which `SpringRunner` first been added(added since 4.3). So `SpringRunner ` should be there.

Comment: I had junit 3.4 which was conflicting I guess after removing that compilation is success still  injected beans are null. I have added Component bas package but didnt work

Comment: For the testng framework, you can remove `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` which is only for junit 4 or higher, **Instead**, make your test class extends from **`AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`** which is spring's test support for testng.

Comment: It is now trying to create data source which was not happening earlier, but somehow test property is not reading, so data source property are null I am checking that

Comment: OK, `@EnableConfigurationProperties` used on the test class may help you for this case.